# Unexpected loop behaviour in bash for loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, syntax

Why does this code not execute the for loop in bash but print what it should loop over? How would execute the for loop like this?

```sh
read N R 
for i in {0..$[(N-1)*R]..$R};do
echo $i;done
```

[image]
[image]

Yes the code looks horrible but it was for a least amount of characters code challenge.

Comment: Are you reading two variables N and R?

Comment: For code challenge purposes, you might want to consider `eval 'read N R; for i in {0..$[(N-1)*R]..$R}; do echo $i; done'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea for dynamically generating the desired range:

```
read N R

for i in $(seq 0 ${R} $(( (N-1)*R )) )
do
    echo $i
done
```

And reducing to the least number of characters:

```
read N R;for i in $(seq 0 $R $((N*R-R)));do echo $i;done
```

Though, generally speaking, I'd probably opt for something like:

```
$ cat ezrah
read N R

for (( i=0 ; i<= (N-1)*R ; i=i+R ))
do
    echo $i
done
```

A couple sample runs:

```
$ ezrah
3 4
0
4
8

$ ezrah
6 3
0
3
6
9
12
15
```